# DevOps: How to use the Branch Filters correctly on pull request

Tags: azure-devops

Our repo has the following branch structure - feature branches -> QA -> master.  We have three build pipelines as well, one for QA, one for master, and one for Dev, which handles all the feature branches. The build pipeline is a simple YAML file, and there is no release pipeline as this is a web app and build pipeline has a `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` step. The pipeline contains nothing other than `name`, `pool`, `variables`, and `steps`, which is the standard nuget/build/publish tasks.

I am using the Triggers to enable CI, however when I complete a pull request from QA to master branch, I am seeing a build kick off for the master branch, and a build kick off for the dev/feature branch. How do I avoid the build for the dev/feature branch?

Here is the trigger defined for the Dev pipeline:

[image]

The trigger for the master build pipeline has `Include = master` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I did [post to the DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/756942/ci-branch-filter-trigger-not-excluding-properly.html?childToView=758851#comment-758851) forum and it turns out to be by design.  It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#git-filters) that if you add `Exclude` filter, you *must* add `Include` filter.

> - If you don't set path filters, then the root folder of the repo is implicitly included by default.
> - When you add an explicit path filter, the implicit include of the root folder is removed. So make sure to explicitly include all folders that your build needs.

TO fix my issue, I simply added `Include = *`, which avoid building in the development pipeline on a completed pull request to QA and master branch.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue ,you need to add a "path filter" so you can exclude the exact file from triggering a PR build.

[image]

**Note** :The path filter option is not available for BitBucket repositories.

Here is a [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1381)(Branch Filter Exclude not Working with Pull-Request Trigger) have the same problem with you ,please refer to it .

Previous user voice has been closed because the forum migration, you could add your request on our new [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

Comment: If I add a Path filter, then the pipeline build won't execute even for the feature branches.

Comment: You can add include feature branch in Branch filters. In addition,Path filters can also be  set to exclude something.

Comment: I don't know the feature branch at run time, and there is no prefix that I can filter with either.  Feature branches are created as `<workitemnumber>_<desc>`.  I understand how Path filters work, they are not applicable for what we are trying to do, which is basically to kick off a build for any other branch except master and QA.

Comment: I think this issue could be a bug ,you can report it on our [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) .

Comment: OK, this is not a bug, it is as designed ,as document said if you add Exclude filter, you must add Include filter. Glad to hear you find the reason of the issue.